# jQuery v3.0 writes unbind not supported anymore, really?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JavaScript Query says that since v3.0 the unbind() is no longer supported and needs to be replaced with off(). Anyways I am using the latest version v3.5 and use `$("#myelement").unbind("click");` all the time and all works nicely... so the unbind() is not deprecated??? I am so confused, should I worry?

Link:
https://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been *deprecated*, but not *removed*.

If you see `unbind` in your code, you should replace it with `off`. `unbind` *may* get removed at some point in the future, like when/if jQuery 4 comes out. But `unbind` will still work if you're using current versions of jQuery.

If you refactor now, you can save yourself from headaches later, when you only find that things aren't working once clients start experiencing runtime errors after you tried to upgrade the jQuery version.

(Or it may be that `.unbind` never gets removed, and that it can be used indefinitely - but who can say what the future holds?)